# How to make Parcel build without JavaScript

Tags: javascript, tailwind-css, postcss, parceljs, posthtml

We have a small static site based on Tailwind, PostCSS and PostHTML that doesn't contain any JS/TS code or `<script>`-tag whatsoever.

However, building with Parcel 2.6.0 yields a 19kb large javascript file (+ a 28kb large map file) in the `/dist`-folder that is included in the generated index.html, which is pointless and generates unnecessary payload and requests.

I could not find anything in the [documentation](https://parceljs.org/languages/html/#inline-scripts-and-styles) regarding this, also simply setting [`"transformers"`](https://parceljs.org/languages/javascript/#usage-with-other-tools) to `false` or similar in `.parcelrc` did not work to disable this behaviour.

How can i get a generated bundle in the `/dist`-folder free of any JavaScript?

Comment: If you don't need it, why not delete the JS?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Thought about that, although it's still a waste of CPU cycles. How would you then automate that so it becomes part of the existing build commands?

Comment: I have the same issue, I don't need any javascript but the parcel build includes a javascript file and an even larger map file.